# segfault trying to find bottom nodes of tree and adding to dynamic array in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, malloc, realloc

when calling init_model() function I am trying to recursively travel through a tree and append the pointers to the lowest treenodes in an array of treenode pointers. however I am getting segfault when I traverse the list trying to print it.

```
void rec_find_inputs(TreeNode* root, TreeNode** arr, int* len_arr) {
    if (!(root->num_children)) {
        arr = realloc(*arr, *len_arr * sizeof(TreeNode*));
        arr[*len_arr] = root;
        (*len_arr)++;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < root->num_children; i++) {
            rec_find_inputs(root->children[i], arr, len_arr);
        }
    }
}


void init_model(TreeNode* neuron_config) {
    int rec_params_len = 0;
    TreeNode** rec_params_arr = (TreeNode**) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode*) * 1);

    rec_find_inputs(neuron_config, rec_params_arr, &rec_params_len);

    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("%d\n", rec_params_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < rec_params_len; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", rec_params_arr[i]->data);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it is a problem with how I am allocating the memory or if I am iterating through the array incorrectly.

Comment: Compile with `-g -O -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined` options (assuming you're using gcc or clang) and see if that narrows down the problem when you run the resulting program

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @Tomas Whiteley What is the initial value of len_arr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet

```
arr = realloc(*arr, *len_arr * sizeof(TreeNode*));
arr[*len_arr] = root;
```

is invalid.

There are allocated `*len_arr` elements of an array. So the valid range of indices is `[0, *len_arr)`. However there is used the invalid index `*len_arr` outside the range

```
arr[*len_arr] = root;
```

Another problem is that you need to pass the pointer `arr` by reference through a pointer to it. That is the function declaration should look at least like

```
void rec_find_inputs(TreeNode* root, TreeNode*** arr, int* len_arr) {
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise the original pointer passed to the function as an argument will stay unchanged.